# A trait class to detect whether a template is specialized for a given type

Tags: c++, template, c++14, sfinae

Today's question will just be about a small utility that I needed at some point for one of my projects: a template to detect whether a template is specialized for a given type. The utility uses [`std::void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) from C++17, but this alias template is simle enough to be implemented in you favourite C++ revision, whichever it is:

```
template<typename...>
struct voider
{
    using type = void;
};

template<typename... TT>
using void_t = typename voider<TT...>::type;
```

Here is the template utility I wrote to detect whether a template has a specialization for a given type, for SFINAE purpose:

```
template<
    template<typename...> class,
    typename,
    typename=void
>
struct is_specialized:
    std::false_type
{};

template<
    template<typename...> class Template,
    typename T
>
struct is_specialized<Template, T, std::void_t<decltype(Template<T>{})>>:
    std::true_type
{};
```

And here is a small example of how it can be used:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo;

template<>
struct foo<int> {};

template<>
struct foo<float> {};

int main()
{
    // Should print 1 1 0
    std::cout << is_specialized<foo, int>::value << ' '
              << is_specialized<foo, float>::value << ' '
              << is_specialized<foo, double>::value;
}
```

Is there any way I could improve this specialization trait? Any kind of review is welcome :)

Comment: You obviously built this for something. What is your use case that makes it valuable. static_assert that specific specializations are made? Asserting that the correct header file with specializations has been included?

Comment: @LokiAstari That was for a library with identity elements. That was to say "if there is a left identity element for this type/operation pair, pick it, otherwise check whether there is a specialization for the general identity element", but I found a simpler alternative meanwhile. You know how it is: you develop a tool and *then* find the obvious solution that you needed but couldn't see until there.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953969/can-static-assert-check-if-a-type-is-a-vector/31923386#31923386) has a solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there's an issue with wording here. What you're testing is if a given instantiation of a class template is default constructible. You're not testing if it's "specialized". You cannot check for that. How would you differentiate between:

```
template <typename T> struct foo { };
template <> struct foo<int> { };

// is foo<X> the primary or the specialization?
```

Back to your example - just because you cannot construct an object of a particular instantiation (e.g. `foo<double>`) doesn't mean that you can't *name* the type. You can do that just fine. That lets you simplify your trait down to:

```
template <typename, typename=void>
struct is_specialized : std::false_type
{};

template<typename T>
struct is_specialized<T, void_t<decltype(T{})>>
    : std::true_type
{};
```

Which you would use as `is_specialized<foo<int>>::value` (`true`) or `is_specialized<foo<double>>::value` (`false`).

But really, since we're just testing for constructibility, we should just use what's in the standard:

```
template <typename T>
using is_specialized = std::is_default_constructible<T>;
```

Comment: Ok, now I feel stupid, I could indeed have used `is_default_constructible` for my needs .______.

Comment: That's what I get for overthinking things.